# Can't echo POST data after onSelect event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am adding a onSelect function on datepicker to Post the selected value using ajax and echo post data using load function

My jquery code is

```
 $('#merchant_datepicker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function (formattedDate,date,inst) {
     var merchant_datepicker = $('#merchant_datepicker').val();
     {
         $.ajax({
            url:'../calendar.php',
            method:"POST",
            data:{merchant_datepicker:merchant_datepicker},
            success:function(data){
                $('#order_wrap').load("../calendar.php");
                alert(data);
            }
         });
     }
  }

});
```

and my calendar.php is

```
<?php 

$new_date=$_POST["merchant_datepicker"];
echo $new_date;
?>

<p>Hello</p>
```

I am getting the data in alert and also div#order_wrap shows "Hello" after selecting a date but I can't echo the $_POST["merchant_datepicker"]

Please help. Thanks

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score -1):

You are currently making two requests to `calendar.php` (one is the ajax POST, the other is the `.load()` call).  If you just want to take the response of the POST and put it in to `#order_wrap`, use the `data` var that you already have.

`$('#order_wrap').html(data);`

Or instead of [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString) maybe [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`.prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) depending on what exactly you're wanting to do.

Comment: Even I think this is the reason because after POSTing the data the load function is reloading the php file and hence I am getting NULL result. Any idea how to fix this because I just want to use that selected data as a variable in another function.

Comment: That's a completely different question from what you posted. The selected value is `$('#merchant_datepicker').val()`. Use it however you want.  I already told you how to use the response from the POST.  If you are trying to do something else, you should rethink your question.